# Change topic on pcd_to_pointcloud

Tags: pcl

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi- Does anyone know how to change the topic that a pointcloud is being published on using pcd_to_pointcloud? On the wiki it only says you can change the frame_id, like so:

$ rosrun pcl_ros pcd_to_pointcloud cloud_file.pcd 0.1 _frame_id:=/odom

pcd_to_pointcloud publishes on the default /cloud_pcd topic, but I'd like to specify my own topic. I tried changing _frame_id:=/ to _topic:=/my_topic but that doesn't seem to work.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/60505/change-topic-on-pcd_to_pointcloud/) by [mdegges](https://answers.ros.org/users/4247/mdegges/) on ROS Answers with karma: 57 on 2013-04-11

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mdegges](https://answers.ros.org/users/4247/mdegges/) on 2013-04-11**:
Edit: The above works fine if I want to look at just one pointcloud. I set the fixed frame to whatever (/base_link, in the wiki) and the topic stays as /cloud_pcd. But I can only view one cloud at a time in rviz. I would like to see multiple pointclouds on the same rviz screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You need to use [Remapping Arguments](http://www.ros.org/wiki/Remapping%20Arguments) the _ is for parameters.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2013-04-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mdegges](https://answers.ros.org/users/4247/mdegges/) on 2013-04-11**:
What do you mean by 'the _is for parameters'?

**Comment by [mdegges](https://answers.ros.org/users/4247/mdegges/) on 2013-04-11**:
hey, I figured it out. I needed to change the namespace, and the directions were right there in your link. thanks for your help!!

**Comment by [sophvk](https://answers.ros.org/users/40739/sophvk/) on 2022-07-04**:
For anyone struggling with this, it all means that you need to do: /cloud_pcd:=/your_topic